# git pull reverts changes

Tags: git, gitlab

I committed and pushed a change to git in a branch, but then realized that some of it was incorrect.  I deleted the incorrect part, and am trying to amend the original commit, because that is the standard of my organization.  However, when I try to push to remote, it says:

hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

And then when I git pull, it reverts my changes to that of the original commit (the deleted part reappears).  How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by joran your upstream has fallen out of sync with local as you amended. If you're going to use `force` I would recommend using `--force-with-lease` as it only force pushes if no one other than you, committed in the upstream.

*This saves you writing over colleagues work, as it will only force replace your work*

Generally however I believe its better to branch off again.

```
git checkout -b "my-feature-branch-fix"
git push -u origin my-feature-branch-fix
```

Once you've done this and had it merged go back and delete your old branch

`git branch -D branch_name`

This takes longer but its safer as you're keeping both copies until everythings merged and your git history more accurately represents what actually happened.

Answer (score 0):

When you *ammend* a commit that is pushed you rewrite your local history by replacing the old commit with a new one, that is, the new commit will have the same parent as the old one.

Before:

```
x---x---P---O <--- master, origin/master
```

After ammend:

```
x---x---P---A <--- master
         \
          +-O <--- origin/master
```

When pushing this state to origin git detects that your (local) branch is one commit behind the remote repo, the old commit, and aborts.

To rewrite the history on the remote repo you need to force the push to origin

```
git push --force origin
```

After push --force:

```
x---x---P---A <--- master, origin/master
```

Now, all you have to do is to deal with teammates that already have pulled the old commit.

This part may be incomplete, but have been sufficient for us in some situations.
Those who do not have any local commits could fetch and reset their local `master` branch to the new `origin/master`

```
git fetch
git checkout master
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Anyone who have any local changes, based on the old commit, could stash or commit to a local branch (a temporary branch from where they can cherry-pick local commits) before they fetch and reset.